# spring-xd-module-parent version 1.3.1.release only support elastic search 1.3.2. Any option to interact with elastic search 2.x?

Tags: spring-xd, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my maven project I try to develop my own spring xd processor that store infos in elastic search version 2.3.3.

I followed the sample found on the spring xd website and the common way to do it is to have the spring-xd-module-parent as parent pom. This brings all the necessary dependencies. I took the last stable version available (1.3.1.RELEASE).

The thing is it has elastic search version 1.3.2 and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 1.2.3.RELEASE as dependencies. When I try to run my test that simply tries to insert a document in my elastic search I get an exception like :

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:173)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unsupported version: 1
at org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:46)
```

compatibility issue from what I understand...

Is there a way like in spring boot to not use the parent pom approach and use the dependency management approach that gives the possibility to override the version of some dependencies ? I didn't find any sample like this.
- if yes, Will it work at deployment time in spring-xd 1.3.1.RELEASE as I have the impression it has been built to work with elastic search 1.3.1 ?

- if it is not possible to integrate with elastic search 2.x, do you see any workaround I can do in spring ? My processor is a step inside a stream so if I cannot do it straight forward maybe there is a workaround I can do in my design to make this work until a future release ? I don't want to rollback to elastic search 1.x

Comment: Even the spring-xd-module-parent-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT includes Elasticsearch 1.3.2 at max. You would need to explicitly include spring data elasticsearch 2.0
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
` 
I am still not sure that it would work, as Spring Autoconfigure for current XD versions may not support new classes. One workaround is to import native Elasticsearch directly and use their services instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I finally used the elastic search api directly. I tried the explicit include of the dependency but didn't work for me.

Comment: Great! In case you're looking to use Spring-data-elasticsearch later, make sure that you use Spring-boot 1.4+ to work with ES 2.
Here is the [dependency matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix).